# android emulator get connection to localhost visual studios

Tags: c#, android, android-emulator, localhost, httpurlconnection

Oh ok so on the android emulator I am trying to parse Json and I am using Visual Studio C# as the web service in between. Each time I fire of the emulator it returns Null, how can I fix this? I have uploaded that Json file to my website and it works correctly but can't see to make it work on the emulator. The file is called **tryjson.json** and I can get to it on the internet by using 
http://localhost:62446/tryjson and my website http://www.website.com/tryjson
on the emulator I am trying http://10.0.2.2:62446/tryjson and http://10.0.2.2/tryjson yet they return null what can possibly be wrong? I know that the Json is correct because if I do http://www.website.com/tryjson in the emulator URL it comes back. The issue is obviously something with the localhost connection but I do not know what.

Answer (score 0):

The alias " http://10.0.2.2:62446/tryjson" should have worked, since the documentation says that for localhost requests you should use this adress (http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html).

But try using your ip adress.
If you use windows, open cmd and type

```
ipconfig
```

you should see your ip adress, something like 192.168.X.XXX.

Use it in the url your app is requesting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your own webserver?  Make sure the webserver is launched with `0.0.0.0` as the host (instead of `localhost`).

Often web servers default to `localhost` which means the server will only listen to requests on `127.0.0.1`.  Using `0.0.0.0` will make the server listen on any IP.